# Как сделать этот класс статическим?

Tags: java

```
public class MarkerList {
    ArrayList<String> lat=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lng=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> type_2=new ArrayList<>();//Type_2

    public void setLat(String str) {
        this.lat.add(str);
    }
    public void setLng(String str) {
        this.lng.add(str);
    }
    public void setName(String str) {
        this.name.add(str);
    }
    public void setType_2(String str) {
        this.type_2.add(str);
    }

    public String getLat(int pos) {
        return lat.get(pos);
    }
    public String getLng(int pos) {
        return lng.get(pos);
    }
    public String getName(int pos) {
        return name.get(pos);
    }
    public String getType_2(int pos) {
        return type_2.get(pos);
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return name.size();
    }
}
```

Хочу чтобы не создавать во всем коде раз 10 ArrayList. А чтобы создать один раз и добавить туда данные. А после уже брать оттуда все что нужно мне.

Правильно ли я делаю вообще? или это гавнокод?

Comment: Я так понимаю что во все списки значения заносятся одновременно, почему не создать класс с этими 4 полями и потом сделать 1 статический список этого класса?

Comment: @pavel, можно подробнее чуток.Я не полностью понял вашу мысль. Но суть да такая. У меня списков много и создавать 5 штук. А после из одного класса каждый список передавать это дикость. Поэтому хотел как то в один файл залить и передавать один файл.

Ну или статический использовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно можно сделать и статическими поля (добавить модификатор static) и это позволит при создании любого количества экземпляров использовать одни и те же коллекции.

Но то, что Вы описываете:

> Хочу чтобы не создавать во всем коде раз 10 ArrayList. А чтобы создать
>   один раз и добавить туда данные. А после уже брать оттуда все что
>   нужно мне.

можно реализовать с помощью паттерна [Одиночка(Singleton)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), в данном случае подойдет самый простой вариант реализации шаблона:

```
public class MarkerList {
    public static final MarkerList INSTANCE = new MarkerList(); 
    ArrayList<String> lat=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lng=new ArrayList<>();
```

Получить доступ к экземпляру можно будут следующим образом:

```
MarkerList myLists = MarkerList.INSTANCE;
```

---

Так же необходимо учесть, что после того как вы замените локальные экземпляры классов на статический или Singleton у Вас могут возникнуть проблемы с параллельным доступам к данной коллекции из разных потоков. Простейший способ сделать применимой текущею реализацию в многопоточной среде - это использовать `Collections`. Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
List<String> lat = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```